# I don't understand how scoping works in this case

Tags: javascript, debugging

Why is abc undefined in first output, then printed out in the final console.log ? I would expect hello world hello...

```js
var abc = 'hello';

function test() {
  console.log(abc);

  var abc = "world";
  console.log(abc);

}

test();
console.log(abc);
```

Comment: Because `var abc;` is *hoisted* to the top of the function.

Comment: It is undefined because local `var` variables are hoisted to their functions.  So the local `abc` doesn't have a value until you give it one

Comment: When a specific variable defined in a local scope, any reference of it will looking for a value of the local variable, which mean (for the references before initialization) `undefined` if the variable sefined as `var`, or *throw error* if the variable defined as `let`

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand this concept. Thanks for your clarifications.